# Node js connect to Photoshop

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp, photoshop

I am looking for example and documentation about the socket connection to photoshop. I tried to figuring out how they did this [generator-core](https://github.com/adobe-photoshop/generator-core).

What i want to do is connect to photoshop. Tell photoshop to open a file, run a actionscript on the photo and then save it.